# xcode adding buttons to navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am making a simple app to display drink details, and now I am trying to add a view that allows the user to input their own drink. I already created a view to display the details, and now I am just passing the view into another controller to make the add drink view. Problem is, when I try to add a "cancel" and "save" button, it doesn't appear, although the code complies without any errors. I have attached code as reference.

This is the code that makes the new view, when the add button is pressed. (I made an add button that works, and it pulls up the nav bar)

```
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    AddDrinkViewController *addViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailSecond"];
    UINavigationController *addNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addViewController];

    [self presentModalViewController:addNavController animated:YES];



    NSLog(@"Add button pressed!");
```

This is the code from the addviewcontroller implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(save:)];

}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Save Pressed");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Cancel Pressed");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I have imported the header from the addview into the root controller, so I don't think that is the problem, do any of you guys see anything that's wrong?

Comment: I think it could be a problem with the fact that I have a tab bar controller, or how I have made the nav bar with the storyboard. I am trying to learn with storyboards, but the book I am using hasn't been updated with that stuff yet and still is using nib files.

Comment: Does the navigation bar appear or not?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line

```
[self presentModalViewController:addNavController animated:YES];
```

to

```
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and see the magic. I also tested the code

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you is to create a template for the view before you run through any code in the XIB file of your app. Rather than trying to set each button after allocating a brand new view, setting a new one in the XIB before-hand allows you to link each element with the app and make sure it looks just right before you debug.

Simply go into your "[Your-App-Name]viewController.xib" and drag a view from the objects library to the pane on the left. From here add each of your elements and position them where you want on the view. Now in the "[Your-App-Name]viewController.h" file, add IBOutlets for each element that you need to change, and add IBActions for each of the buttons. Also create an IBOutlet for the new view.

```
IBOutlet UIView* addDrinkView;
```

Back in the XIB file, use files owner to link each outlet to each element and each method to each button. Make sure you link the IBOutlet

Now in your "[Your-App-Name]viewController.m" file, you can define each button method and all you need to do to access the new view and dismiss it are the following:

```
-(IBAction)openAddView
{
     [self setView:addDrinkView];
}
-(IBAction)saveButtonPressed
{
     [self setView:view];
     //save code goes here
}
-(IBAction)cancelButtonPressed
{
     [self setView:view];
     //cancel code goes here
}
```

This should be much easier than trying to position everything in code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to see if I can not just create another view, and just pass the view from an already existing one which is basically the same. I'm trying to learn ways to efficiently program and get good habits as I'm just learning.

I have a tab view going into the navigation controller, which is connected to a table view, and that table view has a detail view, which is the view I'm passing into the adddetailviewcontroller.

I have already made the navigation controller, but can't seem to place buttons into it.